# adding identifiers to bubbles in datamaps plugin

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, datamaps

How do we add id's to the datamap bubbles so that we can access an individual bubble like this:

```
    d3.select("#my_bubble_id")
```

If bubbles are declared like this:

```
     var bombs = [{
         name: 'Tsar Bomba',
         radius: 1,
         yeild: 50000,
         country: 'USSR',
         fillKey: 'RUS',
         significance: 'Largest thermonuclear weapon ever tested—scaled down from its initial 100 Mt design by 50%',
         date: '1961-10-31',
         latitude: 40.8499966,
         longitude: 129.666664
       }];
     // draw bubbles for bombs
     map.instance.bubbles(bombs, {
         popupTemplate:function (geography, data) {
                 return ['<div class="hoverinfo"><strong>' +  data.name + '</strong>',
                 '<br/>Payload: ' +  data.yeild + ' kilotons',
                 '<br/>Country: ' +  data.country + '',
                 '<br/>Date: ' +  data.date + '',
                 '</div>'].join('');
         }
     });
```

Answer (score -1):

The way I allowed for this was to change the datamaps library, which is very simple if you know D3.

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's not constructive and doesn't answer OP's question.